# How to add two tabs control in the same window WPF?

Tags: xaml, tabcontrol

I have a page contains a tab Control and I'm trying to add another tab control in this page , I would like to know if I can do this with code?

```
    <!--first tab Control-->

      <TabControl VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="auto" x:Name="TabControl"   Height="280" Grid.Row="2" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" BorderThickness="0">
                </TabControl>

<!--second tab Control-->

                <TabControl VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" x:Name="TabControl"   Height="280" Grid.Row="1" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Grid.Column="0" Margin="-1,-5,10,15" BorderThickness="0" >
      </TabControl>
```

I got this error when I've added the first tab Control :

```
Error  The property "Content" can only be set once.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i guess you removed the initial Grid container from your page.

Try to place your controls within a container

```
<StackPanel>
  <TabControl />
  <TabControl />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution , it seems work but I have used another method ( User control that contains tab control ).